# Display Value Does Not Match Data Value After Split Function

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a macro that parses a string in a cell from my excel sheet and should return the three coordinates in that string. I can get the script to parse the string fine and create a "coordinateHolder" array to hold the three coordinates. My issue is that when I update cells to show the coordinates excel shows does not show the entire coordinate.

For example, if the coordinates string is originally "1234.1324123, 12345.23521, 2384.1234253", my code will update my x, y, and z coordinate cells as "1234.132", "12345", "2384.1234"

Image of what I mean:

[image]

(This one shows scientific notation in the cell and a shortened double in the formula builder bar)

My Code:

```
Dim i, j As Integer
Dim coordinates As String
Dim coordHolder As Variant
i = 2
j = 1

Range("I2:K2").Value = Range("E2:G2").Value

Do While Cells(i, j) <> ""
coordinates = Cells(i, j)
coordinates = Replace(coordinates, ",", "")
coordHolder = Split(coordinates, " ")
For a = 0 To UBound(coordHolder)
    Cells(i, 7 + a) = coordHolder(a)
Next a

i = i + 1
Loop
```

Comment: You can add this line `Cells(i, 7 + a).NumberFormat = "@"` first thing in For loop to force excel take everything as text.

Answer (score 1):

Excel has a limit of 15 digits for numbers. Any number with more digits will lose precision in the lower magnitudes to enable the number display. Your data has values that go beyond the limit and will be truncated.

513402938412.123 shows just 15 digits. The remaining decimal places have been removed. The significance of 4 or more decimals pales in comparison with the magnitude of the value, therefore Excel considers the digits after the third deicmal as dispensable.

If you want to retain all digits in the value, you need to convert it to text and make sure it remains text and is not converted to a number again. To do that, you can precede any number with the apostrophe sign.

If a cell contains the value `5134029388412.12341234` it will be truncated. A cell containing the value `'5134029388412.12341234` will be treated as text and remain intact.